# Smooth movement of MKAnnotation on MKPolyline

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am working on an app that can suggests routes from point A to point B on a map.

I'm drawing the routes using MKPolyline.

My problem is that when the route is suggested and the app user is following the route, user current location (blue dot) can be imprecise (jumps around, especially in center city, even with BestForNavigation LocationManager accuracy).

I would like to have another MKAnnotation in addition to the blue dot current location that would smoothly follow the movement of the user ON THE ROUTE.

I could't find any code to do this. Does any one have any idea or sample code? Maybe using Kalman Filters?

My resources to perform such a task come from LocationManager: MKCoordinates of current location, Speed and Course.

I want to do something like the Map application on iphone. When you are in directions mode, and the route is drawn, as you move in your car blue dot no longer shows estimated current location. Instead it shows your movement on the drawn route (it never leaves the route line unless you turn to a street that is not on the route). It is really cool. I don't know how they do it.

Projecting to the nearest point on the polyline does not work well. Many times the closest polyline to the devices estimated current location is not the polyline (street) you are actually on. But Iphone Map app works very good. I'm sure they don't just project to closest MKPolyline

Comment: just dont use showuserlocation this is used to show that blue annote just simply find the current location coordinate of user and add a custom annotation at that coordinate

Comment: you could calculate somehow the nearest point on the polyline (projection) to the current location and put a custom or a pin annotation there. when a new location is obtained you update this annotation's coordinates.

Comment: Projecting to the nearest point on the polyline does not work well. Many times the closest polyline to the devices estimated current location is not the polyline (street) you are actually on. I want to do something like the Map application on iphone. When you are in directions mode, and the route is drawn, as you move in your car blue dot no longer shows estimated current location. Instead it shows your movement on the drawn route (it never leaves the route line unless you turn to a street that is not on the route). It is really cool. I don't know how they do it. Probably using Kalman Filter.